# question regarding pointer in c language

Tags: c

```
char *sample = "String Value";
```

`&sample` is a pointer to the pointer of `"String Value"`

is the above statement right?

If the above statement right, what is the equivalent of `&sample` if my declaration is

```
char sample[] = "String Value"
```

Comment: sample[] is re-writable while *sample is not..

Comment: Thank you all for your answers & comments.
Thank you to aJ for editing&tagging my question.

This is my first question here & I think i love this site&community!
d(^-^)b

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first one, there are *two* objects being created.

One is a `char *` (pointer-to-char) called `sample`, and the other is an unnamed array of 13 chars containing the characters of the string.  In this case, `&sample` gives the address of the object `sample`, which is the address of a pointer-to-char - so, a pointer-to-pointer-to-char.

In the second example, there's only *one* object being created; an array of 13 chars called `sample`, initialised with the characters of the string.  In this case, `&sample` gives the address of the object `sample` - so, a pointer-to-array-of-13-chars.

In the second example, there is no "equivalent" to `&sample` in the first example, in the sense of a pointer-to-pointer-to-char value.  This is because there **is** no pointer-to-char value to take the address of.  There is only the array.

Comment: Thank you caf.
You really deserved that 25k reputation!

Comment: Both examples have two objects. They both have the string literal (an array of char). In the first one, a pointer is created which points to the string literal. In the second one, an array is created which contains a copy of the string literal.

Answer (score 0):

While pointers provide enormous power and flexibility to the programmers, they may use cause manufactures if it not properly handled. Consider the following precaustions using pointers to prevent errors. We should make sure that we know where each pointer is pointing in a program. Here are some general observations and common errors that might be useful to remember. `*ptr++, *p[],(ptr).member`

Answer (score 0):

In the first part **&sample** will return the address of 'sample' pointer created and in the second case the starting address of the string created as object.

Answer (score -1):

In C arrays and pointers are more or less interchangable. You can treat an array name like it is a pointer, and a pointer like it is an array name.

If you take the address of (`&`) of a pointer, of course you get a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Taking the address with `&` is, however, one of those times when you *can't* treat an array name like it is a pointer, and vice-versa.

Comment: "more or less interchangeable" does not actually clarify anything for a beginner. (1) "The same thing," is not equivalent to "sometimes a variable declared as an array decays to a pointer to the start of the array," and (2) you'd do better to list the situations when that happens.

Answer (score -2):

&sample is the address of the pointer that points to "String Value".

For the second example, since an array name that is not followed by a subscript is interpreted as the pointer to the initial element of the array, which means

```
sample
```

and

```
&sample[0]
```

are the same, therefore &sample is also the address of the pointer that points to the string.

Comment: This is not true.  `&sample` is *not* the address of a pointer; it is the address of an array, which is in no way interchangeable with the address of a pointer.

Comment: In the second example, `sample` is an array.  In *certain contexts*, it will decay into a pointer automatically, but the distinction is important. (For example, `sizeof sample` and `sizeof &sample[0]` will be different.)